# GZIP не сжимает javascript файлы

Tags: javascript, gzip

Адрес сайта - omiksagro.com Работаю над оптимизацией. Столкнулся с тем, что html и css сжимаются нормально. JS файлы передаются без сжатия.
Заголовки показывают, что сервер - nginx. Сайт на виртуальном хостинге, поэтому доступа к настройкам сервера не имею.
В чём может быть причина и как я могу это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Обратиться к хостеру, очевидно

Comment: @Alexey Ten Та пытаюсь достучаться. Пока молчит. Видимо, судьба моя переезжать на другой хост. Кстати, создал тестовую площадку на другом хосте. Слил туда сайт. Так там проблемы такой нет.

Comment: Рядом кладешь файлы .js.gz или как сжимаешь?

Comment: @eri Пробовал и динамическое сжатие, и статическое. Делал по разным инструкциям, найденным на просторах. Динамическое сжатие просто не работает. Конкретно js файлов. Статическое сжатие опрокидывало мой сайт с ошибкой 500, хотя, я может что-то не то прописывал в .htaccess. Пока ещё не силен в написании инструкций серверу.